Как отправить сообщение определенному Id в Router Aiogram3
Смотрите, пишу код, не особо понимаю роутеры. Мне надо отправить сообщение списку ChatId но как мне это сделать если bot нельзя вроде использовать в handlers
код
@router.message()
async def send_messagee(message: Message):
    if message.reply_to_message and message.reply_to_message.text.lower() == "рассылка":
        text = message.text
        with open('users.json', 'r') as file:
            users_data = json.load(file)
        chat_id = [user['id'] for user in users_data]
        print(text)
        #ТУТ ОТПРАВКА должа быть всем chat_id
        await message.reply("Рассылка выполнена успешно!")


Как это нельзя? Можно.
Прописываешь его и используешь:
async def send_messagee(message: Message, bot: Bot):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=1234567890, text="Text")

